# How to make border missing if img doesn't exist

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide the border with javascript but doesnt work and is possible if try to hide border in html with java?

.........................

[this is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOlqS.png)

this is my html:

```
<!-- Single Product Details -->
<div class="small-container single-product">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="Fn_Img/images/_Snake_ White Tee — Yeaaah! Studio.png" width="100%">
            <div class="small-img-row">
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="Fn_Img/images/gallery-1.jpg" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="Fn_Img/images/gallery-2.jpg" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="Fn_Img/images/gallery-3.jpg" width="100%">
                </div>
                <div class="small-img-col">
                    <img src="" width="100%">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.single-product{
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.single-product .col-2 img{
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.single-product .col-2{
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.single-product h4{
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.single-product select{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;   
}
.single-product input{
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.col-2 img{
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
.single-product .fa{
    color: #ff523b;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.small-img-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.small-img-col{
    flex-basis: 24%;
}
```

problem:

1. i want the border none if img doesn't exist
2. if img none the padding stays in place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following CSS. It may helpful.

```css
.single-product{
    margin-top: 80px;
}
.single-product .col-2 img{
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.single-product .col-2{
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}
.single-product h4{
    margin: 20px 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.single-product select{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;   
}
.single-product input{
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
input:focus{
    outline: none;
}

.col-2 img[src*=".jpg"] {
    border: 1px solid #555;
}
.col-2 img[src=""] {
    border: none;
    padding: 30px; /*use your required custom padding here*/
}
.single-product .fa{
    color: #ff523b;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.small-img-row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.small-img-col{
    flex-basis: 24%;
}
```

```html
<div class="small-container single-product">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300.jpg/09f/fff" width="100%">
          <div class="small-img-row">
              <div class="small-img-col">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg/09f/fff" width="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg/09f/fff" width="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg/09f/fff" width="100%">
              </div>
              <div class="small-img-col">
                  <img src="" width="100%">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: also `.col-2 img:not([src=""]){
    border: 1px solid #555;
}` provides same result.